# ASP.NET Debug server without debugging IE

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have an ASP.NET application in visual studio 2010, and whenever I start debugging, it attaches the debugger to IE as well as the server, which just creates loads more bloat and makes everything run slowly.

How can I start debugging on the server only?

Andy

Answer (score 2):

Once the application is deployed to IIS, you can use Visual Studio on the server to [attach to the web process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx). Also, see [how to debug deployed web applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b00hf3c0.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that. What I was hoping for is a simple way to just press F5 to start debugging the server but not IE

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to start debugging of an ASP.NET site in Visual Studio without it launching a browser. So set the default browser to a different browser that you want to use so you don't waste spawning an IE instance. From [Setting a Default Browser for Visual Studio](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2007/08/02/setting-a-default-browser-for-visual-studio.aspx):

1. Open a WebForm file in VS (anything ending in .aspx will do)
2. Select the "Browse With..." option from the File menu
3. Select your preferred browser from the list and click the "Set as Default" button

Answer (score 1):

One way is to browse with option by clicking the browse with option and the other way is to set the default browser as any other browser than IE